Name servers from tld-servers
Let us take google.com.
If I run:
host -t ns com.

I get a list of servers that are name servers for .com. E.g. c.gtld-servers.net.
I had expected that if I run:
host -t ns google.com c.gtld-servers.net.

I would get the name servers for google.com. But I do not:
Using domain server:
Name: c.gtld-servers.net.
Address: 192.26.92.30#53
Aliases: 

google.com has no NS record

Yet my resolver can find the name servers no problem:
$ host -t ns google.com
google.com name server ns2.google.com.
google.com name server ns4.google.com.
google.com name server ns3.google.com.
google.com name server ns1.google.com.

What is going on here? How can I ask c.gtld-servers.net to give me the name servers for google.com?

I don't have an answer (yet?) but contrast host -r -t ns google.com c.gtld-servers.net and host -vr -t ns google.com c.gtld-servers.net

@ChrisDavies Ahh. That might explain where the resolver gets the info from.

I suspect it's that glue/stub records don't quite act as NS records but are rather seen as referrals. So when you ask for the NS you get told "No...but they'll know". But I'm not familiar enough with the relevant RFCs to give a definitive answer

This over on StackOverflow appears to answer your question → what is "additional section" in DNS and how it works?

Hmm... dig google.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net gives exactly what I expect: the name for 4 name servers with some additional info (the IP-addresses of these 4) that I can choose to ignore. Maybe host is simply b0rken. nslookup is acts similar to host -v.
